# Command Object in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a help command and I want to print the paramater names of a command. I have a command object and i'm using command.params but i don't know how to extract the values from it

```
@client.command()
async def Help(ctx):
    embed = Embed(title="Available Commands")
    for command in client.commands:
        params = command.params
        print(params)
        embed.add_field(name=f"{command.name}{command.params}", value=f"{command.brief}", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

currently it returns:

```
OrderedDict=([('ctx', < Parameter "ctx" >), ('card', < Parameter "card" >)])
```

How do i extract the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explore the list in a for loop, and then, you append the item that you want in a list :

- If you only want the param name

```py
OrderedDict=([('ctx', < Parameter "ctx" >), ('card', < Parameter "card" >)])

params = []
for item in OrderedDict:
    params.append(item[0])
```

- If you only want the param object

```py
OrderedDict=([('ctx', < Parameter "ctx" >), ('card', < Parameter "card" >)])

params = []
for item in OrderedDict:
    params.append(item[1])
```

- If you want both

```py
OrderedDict=([('ctx', < Parameter "ctx" >), ('card', < Parameter "card" >)])

params = {}
for item in OrderedDict:
    params[item[0]] = item[1]
```